# How to input multiple commands or loop a command in Command Prompt using C++?

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, snmp

I am trying to display the results of my commands live. I am already able to retrieve the results, but I want a live stream. Whenever I put a while loop into my code to repeat the command, a window opens, the command executes, then the window closes, then another window opens and the process repeats until the program crashes. I want the command prompt to run in the background while receiving commands because I am running a QT gui in front of it.

Here is my code currently:

```
cmd = _popen("snmpget -v 2c -c public 192.168.127.101 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8691.8.4.6.1.1.3.1.1.4.1", "r"); //input command in format (snmp_function -v version -c community_string IP_address OID)
if (cmd == NULL)
{
    perror("_popen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd))          //gets full responce string to snmpget and passes string to result variable
{
    std::string str = result;                       //sets string to values in variable result
    std::regex rgx("\"([^\"]*)\"");                 //retrieves only the section of the output string that is between double air quotes
    std::smatch match;
    std::string buffer;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
                                                //necessary? whitespace
    while (ss >> buffer)
        strings.push_back(buffer);
    for (auto& i : strings)
    {
        if (std::regex_match(i, match, rgx))
        {
            std::ssub_match submatch = match[1];
            std::string str = submatch.str();
            for (size_t j=0; j<str.length(); j++)
            {
                output[j] = str[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

_pclose(cmd);
```

The `std::string` stuff is just to get the part of the return value I want.
I can normally hold the window open by putting in a `getchar()` at the end of a `while` loop that contains this, but I don't want to be reliant on the user pressing enter to get an updated result.

Comment: Unless your problem has something to do with Qt, you should not use that tag.

Comment: @RSahu I am running this in Qt. If this was its own program I would be done, I need this to run as my Qt gui is running. I mentioned at the top that this was in Qt.

Comment: I understand. Are you suggesting that if you run the above code without Qt, you don't see any problem?

Comment: @RSahu yes, because I can just hold it open and wait for a user input. As part of my Qt program, it needs to happen passively without user input.

Comment: That does not make sense to me. Hopefully it makes sense to others.

Comment: `"...process repeats until the program crashes"` -- firstly you need to identify the location/cause of the crash using your debugger.  Secondly, if this is being used in association with `Qt` then you need to provide some details as to precisely *how* it's being used with `Qt`.  That being said, you might want to look at using [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) rather than `_popen` -- it should be much easier to incorporate into the `Qt` event processing loop.  Finally, please consider editing your question to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a nested cmd when you execute the first command. Something like:

```
cmd.exe /c cmd.exe /k "Put the command you want to execute here!"
```

Im not sure if quoting the command is necessary but I know that it does work with quotes so that would mean you change your first line to:

```
cmd = _popen("cmd.exe /c cmd.exe /k \"snmpget -v 2c -c public 192.168.127.101 .1.3.6.1.4.1.8691.8.4.6.1.1.3.1.1.4.1\"", "r"); //Note the escaped quotes
```

The above is untested but I believe it should give you the intended result. Note that this opens an inner cmd each time so with this solution you might want to keep track of the exits. Basically for each command that isn't the first one, you will want to send exit to close that inner->inner cmd.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just keeps the command window open and prevents the Qt Gui from running. It also just runs the command once. When looped, it just opens a new cmd when the first is closed.